# Copy a column from one dataset to another

Tags: sas

I have two SAS datasets. Let's call them: `dataset1` and `dataset2`.
They both have the same number of observations and are properly ordered. 
I want to move or copy column `x` from `dataset2` to `dataset1`.

I know I could do it using a `merge` or `join` statement, but from what I understood the only way to do it is to create a `dataset3` which would be `dataset1` and `dataset2` merged.

I would like to avoid that as `dataset1` is 300GB in size. So creating a new `dataset3` would require another 300GB. I would rather find a way of moving column `x` from `dataset2` to `dataset1` without the need of creating an entirely new dataset.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Following the comment below, I am thinking about the following syntax:

```
PROC SQL;
ALTER TABLE work.dataset1 ADD x NUM(8);
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
UPDATE work.dataset1 set x = work.dataset2.x
QUIT;
```

Is the syntax correct?

Comment: I think unlikely to have a better solution, as SAS usually reads in data one line at a time. Could find some joy in using the alter statement in proc sql though: http://www.listendata.com/2016/06/proc-sql-alter-table-and-update-column.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question. Do you see any issue with the syntax above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with adding a new column via `alter table` is that it's not any better than rewriting the dataset - as SAS stores data in such a way that all data for each row is stored together.

See this example:

```
data table1;
  do x = 1 to 1e8;
    output;
  end;
run;
data table2;
  do x = 1 to 1e2;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  alter table table1
    add y num;
quit;
proc sql;
  alter table table2
    add y num;
quit;
```

(Change `1e8` in the `table1` if you have a slower, or faster, SAS install such that it takes at least 5-10 seconds to run, but not hours.)  SAS is clearly rewriting the whole dataset behind the scenes, just as it would if you had a data step merge but with `data table1; merge table1 table2; run;`.

For me, the SQL alter table step for table1 takes longer than the initial datastep (presumably as the file is about double the size).  So, it's not going to save you much time over a data step with a merge or whatever - and this is only performing the column addition; you still need the `update` which will take some significant amount of time as well.

If you're going to add a new column, your *best* way to approach it is to add the new column as an empty column before you create the original dataset.  That way you never need to alter table/etc. and can just update (or data step `modify`) to add the information without altering the table structure.

Assuming that ship sailed, then you've got various ways to approach this depending on how the incoming data is connected to the original dataset, relative sizes, row counts, etc.  Hash table, format, or data step merge are all good for some cases.  You'll want to add some additional information to get the best answer - how big is the second dataset, are either or both sorted already on the common key, in particular.

---

If you're just appending a column directly, then you can do an unkeyed merge:

```
data table1;
  merge table1 table2;
run;
```

This will create a temporary table, so it does not remove the need for 300gb extra space for a time in your utility directory, but I don't think you have a way of not needing that regardless of the solution chosen.  This is probably the fastest solution as it just takes one row from each and writes it out.

---

Just to clarify why this is needed, SAS data is stored like so.

Say you have a datafile with ten rows.  It has one variable per row.  That variable stores the row number and nothing more.  Let's also ignore the header - only looking at the data portion of the file.

Your record size would then be 8 bytes, and let's say based on your setup that one contiguous block is 40 bytes.  (It's way more than that, but for representing on a screen...)

So you might have this stored in data:

```
0000000100000002000000030000000400000005
0000000600000007000000080000000900000010
```

Now, if you want to add another column, let's say the number 99887766 for every row.  It would then be stored like this.

```
0000000199887766000000029988776600000003
9988776600000004998877660000000599887766
0000000699887766000000079988776600000008
9988776600000009998877660000001099887766
```

Notice how that 99887766 is not just put at the end - it's meshed in with the rows.  It's not possible to add this number without rewriting the whole table. SAS does this using your work/utility folder by creating a new file with `.lck` at the end and writes the whole file to it.

If you do something like `alter table` and then open your work directory up as a folder (do the test I show above), you will see two files - the original file and a ".lck" file which grows up to the size of the original file, then SAS deletes the original file and renames the .lck file to the original filename.

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for your answer. 
Dataset1 has 1,029,138,140 rows and 46 columns and Dataset2 has 1,029,138,140 rows and 3 columns. 

I literally just want to move the last column of Dataset2 to Dataset1. No need to worry about sorting and so on as that is taken care of. It is a simple cut column from Dataset2 and paste in Dataset1. 

I was trying to avoid merge/join as they seem to force me to create a new Dataset3 (and I do not have disk space for that).

Comment: @volcompt Understood.  I would be careful doing that - that's not really very good data practice as it's much better to merge on a key rather than assume everything is ordered properly, but of course it depends on what you're doing.  In any event, I don't think you're going to find a solution that doesn't require writing the whole thing over again in some fashion, unless you follow my advice and create `Dataset1` with 47 columns in the first place.  I added some detail to show why.

Comment: Joe, understood. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe If you made a view of the unkeyed merge, would SAS need to create a 300GB temp file when resolving the view?

Comment: @user667489 Maybe, maybe not, but I wouldn't assume it wouldn't.  Sometimes SAS creates temp files to resolve views, sometimes it doesn't, depending on what else is going on.